# Can I get the wallet in bitcoind to use P2SH segwit (on testnet)?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet, segregated-witness

Can I use the wallet functionality in bitcoin cli daemon with P2SH segwit on testnet/regtest? Meaning, can I *receive* on these addresses and send from them?

And if I can, how?

I cannot find it anywhere in the help. The only one that gets close is `addwitnessaddress`, but that does something else, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addwitnessaddress` is what you want

create it, fund it and spend coins from it - then check your transactions on any blockexplorer that they are in segwit format

Comment: When I try to use `addwitnessaddress`, it wants another argument with an address. I don't understand what that argument means.

Comment: private key generates address. then addwitnessaddress adds segwit address generated from your address which can be redeemed with that private key

Comment: Call `getnewaddress` first, and then pass the result to `addwitnessaddress` to convert it to P2SH-embedded P2WPKH. `addwitnessaddress` also works on P2SH multisig addresses (in which case it will produce a P2SH-embedded P2WSH).

Comment: Ooooh. This is a little confusing, IMO, but yeah it works